# TransformException after migrating to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I tried to import a working Eclipse Android project to Android Studio. I am working on Mac with the latest version of Android Studio. When I try to build, it keeps on displaying this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     com/google/api/client/http/AbstractHttpContent.class

The class generating this issue is in the com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0 library, in the com.google.api.client.http package. I tried many things with the app.gradle file, such as excluding the com.google.api.client.http group but nothing works. Here is my app.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.time2"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 19
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
}
```

Comment: http://www.developer.com/ws/android/migrating-from-eclipse-to-android-studio.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid manually adding in libs to your project.

```
E.g. change
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')

to

compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
```

Please verify that these are the correct packages.  Let us know what you find after updating?

Answer (score 2):

The library `'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'` is composed of the following nine modules:

> ```
> google-http-client
> google-http-client-android
> google-http-client-appengine
> google-http-client-xml
> google-http-client-protobuf
> google-http-client-jdo
> google-http-client-jackson
> google-http-client-jackson2
> google-http-client-gson
> ```

Some of these e.g. `google-http-client` is included again in tour dependencies as a `jar`. Hence the duplicate entry.

Check this link for getting the setup right when using `google-http-java-client`. It has step by step instruction - [Setup Instructions](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/setup)